Как различать объекты в полиморфном списке?
Пусть есть какой-нибудь интерфейс, например геометрической фигуры, и у него есть 3 наследника: квадрат, треугольник, 5-угольник. Пусть указатели на них хранятся в одном векторе указателей. Возникает задача, как раскрасить все квадраты в красный цвет, если мы не можем отличить тип фигуры через полиморфный указатель. Я знаю 2 решеня:

Динамик-каст, что является каким-то костылём
Добавить поле вид внутрь объекта, что тоже сомнительно.

Как тогда покрасить в красный цвет только квадраты? Как с такой проблемой работать в общем случае?

Добавьте в базовый интерфейс виртуальный метод раскрашивания.

@user7860670 и написать реализацию для остальных наследников, что я игнорирую окраску в красный?? Это же тоже не решение

Остальные наследники могут не перегружать метод раскраски из базового класса и рисоваться по-умолчанию.

@user7860670 ситуация на проде, все методы уже есть у всех, редактировать нельзя их используют другие компоненты программы. Посмотрел паттерн Visitor но как будто это не для моего случая.

Я бы вспомнил принцип Tell-Dont-Ask. Т.е. говорим элементам в списке, что надо "физзбаззнуться", кто умеет (квадраты), те красятся в красный.

Добавить метод "я квадрат" или аналого type_id. (т.е. dynamic_cast своими руками, но быстрее).

В момент создания квадрата помещать его не только в общий список, но в отдельный список квадратов.

Никак, полиморфный список он не для этого :-)
В общем случае, тут может сработать принцип Tell, Dont Ask. Когда мы не спрашиваем у каждого объекта какой он и не говорим ему по результатам его ответа что ему делать, а сразу помещаем эту логику в объект, чтобы он сам решал, удовлетворяет ли он условиям и имеет ли нужные возможности.

Таким образом у нас может быть более хорошая инкапсуляция логики и полиморфизм, когда внешней системе даже не важно знать что такое квадрат, а достаточно просто "геометрической фигуры" (что по сути и декларируется вашим вектором указателей).

И в результате уже через год никто не понимает, как эта программа на самом деле работает

@avp самое забавное, что это утверждение справедливо для любого подхода ))

Кроме программ с прозрачным кодом (минимум упрятывания деталей структур данных), основанных на KISS-принципе. Ну, да, обычно они просто решают поставленную задачу, не следуют принципам ООП и не претендуют на основу для абстрактных библиотек

Метод .paintYourselfRedIfYouAreSquare хорошо подходит под принцип "Tell, don't ask.", но выглядит как-то сомнительно. Или вопрос про другое?

@StanislavVolodarskiy название плохое, а в остальном - приходит препод по физ-ре в группу студентов и говорит - "всем парням переодеться в красное". Мы считаем, что студенты достаточно взрослые и самостоятельные люди, чтобы их не надо было по одному проверять и переодевать каждого отдельно в штаны нужного размера. Другими словами, чем более самостоятельные сущности, тем больше стоит им делегировать.



Динамик-каст, что является каким-то костылём
Добавить поле вид внутрь объекта, что тоже сомнительно.


Второе - ничем не лучше чем первое (возможно второе быстрее; если вам это важно - профилируйте). В первом нет ничего плохого, иногда это лучшее решение.

Есть три решения, каждое для своих случаев:

Виртуальная функция.
dynamic_cast
(или сравнение typeid, если нужен конкретный класс а не его потомки)
(или поле с указанием типа класса, если это в вашем случае чем-то лучше)
Рядом с объектом хранить указатель на функцию, которая делает то что нужно.

1 - Вариант по умолчанию.
2,3 - Если функции не место в родителе. Например, если классы используются во всем приложении, а такая раскраска нужна в одном месте. Тогда странно тащить ее в общего родителя. (Либо, если родитель - библиотечный, и его нельзя менять.)
3 удобнее, если есть где хранить эту функцию (особенно если объект создаете вы сами - тогда можно и правильную функцию подложить сразу, не изучая тип dynamic_castами), а 2 - если объекты хранятся где-то снаружи, и никакие метаданные к ним не подложить.

Бывают ярые противники dynamic_castов (см. соседний ответ, не в обиду @Kromster), видимо потому что их ругают в умных книжках. Но я пока ни от кого не получил нормального объяснения, что делать в ситуации выше, когда нельзя менять родителя, или функционал слишком специфичный чтобы его туда тащить.

"когда нельзя менять родителя, или функционал слишком специфичный" - подложить под родителя своего общего для всех родителя с нужной функциональностью.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Вот пример из практики. Есть CAD. Трехмерные объекты в сцене - наследники класса Object (библиотечный, менять нельзя), у которого есть список подобъектов который хранится в std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> (объекты образуют дерево). Даже если сделать своего родителя, придется каждый раз кастовать в него каждый Object dynamic_cast-ом (потому что тип элемента списка захардкожен) - смысл теряется. [1/2]

[2/2] Даже если мы это как-то обошли и сделали своего родителя, все равно остается проблема, что функционал раскраски может быть нужен в каком-то одном модуле приложения, и было бы очень странно тащить его в общий класс, который используется везде. (А если модуль с раскраской грузится в рантайме как DLL - то вообще невозможно.)

Просто перестаньте всё делать через один контейнер. При создании объектов помещайте в столько контейнеров, сколько нужно для всех ваших потребностей. Один единственный контейнер подозрительно похож на объекта-бога. Это уже не задача ООП. Принцип подстановки Лисков прямо запрещает интересоваться квадратами. Правда, все его игнорируют.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Наверное на слух непонятно, давайте кодом покажу: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Eq9W5c1vx Вот есть дерево объектов (root), нужно удалить из него объекты определенного типа. Непонятно, как добавить сюда еще контейнеров. (Даже если, допустим, рядом с деревом держать set<Mesh *> где поддерживать актуальный список Meshей, это не поможет, например, если нужно позвать DeleteAllMeshes на под-дереве.)

"Принцип подстановки Лисков" А он разве про это? Как я понимаю, он говорит как нужно проектировать классы-потомки (чтобы их можно было воткнуть вместо родителя, и ничего не сломалось - идея в целом разумная). Где и как хранить экземпляры - ничего не говорит.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Про "объекта-бога". Представьте себе любой CAD (тот же Blender, например). Грубо говоря, есть постоянно существующее дерево объектов, которую вы меняете, тыкая в кнопки. Вот это "объект-бог" или нет? В любом случае, от дерева-синглтона никак не избавиться.

Добавлю вам еще 1 термин, вы его знаете - ECS.

В Блендере реализованы много коллекций, не одно дерево сцены. Если наш контейнер поддерживает операции с элементами по ссылкам/указателям/индексам, то для покраски квадратов имеет смысл держать отдельный список этих ссылок на квадраты. Если наш контейнер не адресует, то я не знаю как решить задачу.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Допустим в каждом узле дерева иметь список указателей на квадраты (прямых потомков), чтобы не искать каждый раз. Все равно остаются вопросы: допустим в динамически загружаемом плагине-DLL есть свой тип потомков, которых он хочет фильтровать - и что делать? (Можно как-то динамически поддерживать несколько списков под разные типы, но это выглядит сложновато, и непонятно, стоит ли это того по сравнению с dynamic_cast-ом.) (Даже если не рассматривать экстремальный случай с DLL, все равно не хотелось бы руками менять родителя при добавлении каждого нового потомка.)

@Kromster А что ECS? Как бы вы в ECS стали искать нужные объекты?

"ECS" (в русской раскладке внезапно - "УСЫ") - это тоже во многом про TDA (только тут мы делегируем системе и списку объектов). Примерно по мотивам того что пишет @StanislavVolodarskiy - когда множество разных контейнеров под разные цели при ином взгляде становятся списками объектов/компонентов умеющих/поддерживающих в те или иные действия (например бытие квадратами и умение в красный).

Определяете базовый класс для "заполнителей":
struct Filler
{
    virtual ~Filler() = default;
    virtual void operator()(Square&) const {}
    virtual void operator()(Triangle&) const {}
    // ...
};

В базовый класс для фигур добавляете чисто виртуальную функцию fill:
struct Shape
{
    virtual ~Shape() = default;
    // ...
    virtual void fill(const Filler&) = 0;
};

В наследниках Shape переопределяете эту функцию:
struct Square : Shape
{
    void fill(const Filler& filler)
    {
        filler(*this);
    }
};

Определяете "заполнитель" только для квадратов:
struct SquareRedFiller
{
    void operator()(Square& s){ /* code */ }
};

Кажется, все :) В SquareRedFiller мы переопределили только оператор для квадратов, все остальные - реализация по умолчанию (которая ничего не делает).

В итоге Filler должен знать про всю иерархию наследования. Даже хуже чем dynamic_cast.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, да, но разве это станет проблемой, если иерархия не изменяется? В вопросе о такой речь идет, разве нет?
